# FFMPEG options for video streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to use ffmpeg to stream video using ffserver. You will find below the ffserver1.conf file, and the log output from the ffmpeg command.

One of the errors references presets, and everytime I try to use presets I get the error "File not found, even after copying all the preset files in the current directory.

Thanks for the help.

YorgZ

```
FFSERVER CONF

YorgZ-Macbook$cat ffserver1.conf
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 4000
CustomLog -


<Feed feed1.ffm>
      File feed1.ffm
      FileMaxSize 1G
      ACL allow 127.0.0.1
      ACL allow localhost
      ACL allow 10.0.0.0 10.0.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream Live.mp4>
    Feed feed1.ffm
    Format mp4
    VideoFrameRate  29.97
    VideoBitRate    500
    VideoSize   640x352
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
    Format status
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 10.0.0.0 10.0.255.255
</Stream>
YorgZ-Macbook$

FFMPEG COMMAND AND LOG 

 YorgZ-Macbook$./ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i TestStream.mp4  -codec:v libx264 -b:v 500k  -vf "scale=640:352" -r 29.97 -codec:a aac -b:a 128k http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm

    ffmpeg version 2.1.3-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Jan 16 2014 13:50:59 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
      configuration: --prefix=/Users/tessus/data/ext/ffmpeg/sw --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libspeex --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libxavs --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libgsm --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-filters --enable-runtime-cpudetect
      libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
      libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
      libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
      libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
      libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
      libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
      libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
      libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
    Splitting the commandline.
    Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
    Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'TestStream.mp4'.
    Reading option '-codec:v' ... matched as option 'codec' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
    Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '500k'.
    Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=640:352'.
    Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '29.97'.
    Reading option '-codec:a' ... matched as option 'codec' (codec name) with argument 'aac'.
    Reading option '-b:a' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '128k'.
    Reading option 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm' ... matched as output file.
    Finished splitting the commandline.
    Parsing a group of options: global .
    Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Parsing a group of options: input file TestStream.mp4.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an input file: TestStream.mp4.
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10201a200] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10201a200] ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10201a200] File position before avformat_find_stream_info() is 33783
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10201a200] All info found
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10201a200] File position after avformat_find_stream_info() is 64138
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'TestStream.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        creation_time   : 2014-02-17 10:17:06
      Duration: 00:01:40.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 582 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und), 15, 1/30000: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1001/60000, 483 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/44100: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-02-17 10:17:06
          handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
    Successfully opened the file.
    Parsing a group of options: output file http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm.
    Applying option codec:v (codec name) with argument libx264.
    Applying option b:v (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 500k.
    Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument scale=640:352.
    Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 29.97.
    Applying option codec:a (codec name) with argument aac.
    Applying option b:a (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 128k.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an output file: http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm.
    [ffm @ 0x102037200] Format ffm probed with size=2048 and score=101
    [AVIOContext @ 0x101d04fe0] Statistics: 4096 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Mon Feb 24 11:53:05 2014 127.0.0.1 - - [GET] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4175
    Successfully opened the file.
    detected 8 logical cores
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x101d05a20] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x101d05a20] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x101d05a20] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x101d05a20] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x101d05a20] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
    [audio format for output stream 0:0 @ 0x102d004e0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
    [audio format for output stream 0:0 @ 0x102d004e0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '22050'
    [audio format for output stream 0:0 @ 0x102d004e0] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x4'
    [audio format for output stream 0:0 @ 0x102d004e0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'audio format for output stream 0:0'
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x101d03ea0] query_formats: 4 queried, 6 merged, 3 already done, 0 delayed
    0.500000 0.500000 
    [auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x102d00ca0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:44100Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:22050Hz
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'video_size' to value '640x360'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/30000'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x103b003a0] w:640 h:360 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/30000 fr:30000/1001 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
    [scaler for output stream 0:1 @ 0x103b00900] Setting 'w' to value '640'
    [scaler for output stream 0:1 @ 0x103b00900] Setting 'h' to value '352'
    [scaler for output stream 0:1 @ 0x103b00900] Setting 'flags' to value '0x4'
    [scaler for output stream 0:1 @ 0x103b00900] w:640 h:352 flags:'0x4' interl:0
    [format @ 0x103b00dc0] compat: called with args=[yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16]
    [format @ 0x103b00dc0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16'
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x102d00fc0] query_formats: 5 queried, 4 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
    [scaler for output stream 0:1 @ 0x103b00900] w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 -> w:640 h:352 fmt:yuv420p sar:44/45 flags:0x4
    [libx264 @ 0x102049800] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
    [libx264 @ 0x102049800] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
    [libx264 @ 0x102049800] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
    [libx264 @ 0x102049800] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
    [libx264 @ 0x102049800] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
    Output #0, ffm, to 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        creation_time   : now
        Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/1000000: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-02-17 10:17:06
          handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
        Stream #0:1(und), 0, 1/1000000: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x352 [SAR 44:45 DAR 16:9], 1001/30000, q=2-31, 500 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (h264 -> libx264)
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
    [AVIOContext @ 0x101d04fe0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
    [AVIOContext @ 0x101d03fa0] Statistics: 65536 bytes read, 0 seeks
    Mon Feb 24 11:53:05 2014 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 0
    YorgZ-Macbook$
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found my own problem. MP4 does not work because it is not seekable, and also I can obviously not output a higher bandwidth than I input ...Duh!!!